# How do I keep the y coordinate and go to a specific x coordinate and vice versa in cirucitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I am making a circuit diagram and want to have each input have the same starting x coordinate. I need the R input to be aligned with P and Q.

The line that would need to be changed is the second to last line before the semicolon. I tried the "-|" notation like this (-1 -| a1.in 2) but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(-1,0) node[label=left:$P$] {} to[short,o-]
(0,0) node[or port, anchor=in 1] (o1) {}
(o1.in 2) to[short,-o] ++(-1,0) node[label=left:$Q$] {}
(o1.out) to ++(0.3,0) node[not port, anchor=in] (n1) {}
(n1.out) -| ++(0.5,-0.5) -- 
++(0.5,0) node[and port,anchor=in 1] (a1) {}
(a1.in 2) to[short,-o] ++(-3,0) node[label=left:$R$] {}
(a1.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0) node[label=right:$S$] {}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The easy solution is to name the node containing P and use `(P |- a1.in 2)`.  To amswer your precise question, use `({-1,0} |- a1.in 2)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(-1,0) node[label=left:$P$] (P) {} to[short,o-]
(0,0) node[or port, anchor=in 1] (o1) {}
(o1.in 2) to[short,-o] (P |- o1.in 2) node[label=left:$Q$] {}
(o1.out) to ++(0.3,0) node[not port, anchor=in] (n1) {}
(n1.out) -| ++(0.5,-0.5) -- 
++(0.5,0) node[and port,anchor=in 1] (a1) {}
(a1.in 2) to[short,-o] (P |- a1.in 2) node[label=left:$R$] {}
(a1.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0) node[label=right:$S$] {}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

Experimenting with Ti*k*Z library `ext.paths.ortho` and `inline not` logic gate, based on nice @Koromylo answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}  % for -|- and |-| path operations

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)       node[label=left:$P$] (P) {}
                    to[short,o-] ++ (0.5,0)
                    node[or port, anchor=in 1]  (o1) {}
        (o1.in 2)   to[short,-o]    (P |- o1.in 2)
                    node[label=left:$Q$] {}
        (o1.out)    to[inline not]  ++ (2,0)    % <---
                    -|- ++  (0.3,-0.5)          % <---
                    node[and port,anchor=in 1]  (a1) {}
        (a1.out)    to[short,-o]    ++ (1,0)
                    node[label=right:$S$] {}
        (a1.in 2)   to[short,-o]    (P |- a1.in 2)
                    node[label=left:$R$] {}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]